# UIView Flip transition not working

Tags: ios, uiview, transition, viewflipper

recently I am doing some project on something like a flip card. I have two subviews inside the view controller and I would like to flip over the subview on click of a button. What I can achieve now is the whole view is flipping but I just want the subview ONLY =( Please let me know what wrong with my code.....;( Thanks guys

```
- (void)test: (id)sender{
[UIView transitionFromView:firstView
                    toView:secondView
                  duration:0.5f
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    /* do something on animation completion */
                }];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 250)];
   secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 250)];
   firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
   [button addTarget:self action:@selector(test:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:button];
   [self.view addSubview:secondView];
   [self.view addSubview:firstView];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a another view (I call it container) to self.view, and add the firstView to that instead of directly to self.view. You don't need to add the second view at all -- the transition does that for you.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 250, 250)];
    firstView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 250, 250)];
    secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 250, 250)];
    firstView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    secondView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(test:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [container addSubview:firstView];
    [self.view addSubview:container];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But can you kindly explain a little bit why we ned a container ?

Comment: @HebitzLau, I wish I could -- it seems like it should work without one from the way the method reads.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend creating an UIView subclass (like container mentioned before) which has two properties: firstView & secondView.
Then implement a "flip" method in that subclass like this:

```
- (void)flip
{
    [UIView transitionFromView:_firstView toView:_secondView ...];
}
```

The reason why whole view is being flipped is because "transitionFromView" looks for a view where it is being called, and does animation there. In your case it is called in viewcontroller, so whole of your view is being flipped. You have to call it in subview, if you want only particular view to be animated.